# NativeScript loadStarted WebView event doesn't trigger on Android

Tags: android, angular, webview, nativescript

I am using a Webview in NativeScript/Angular with a loadStarted and a loadFinished event. On my iPhone (tns run ios) both events are triggered. On my Android phone (tns run android) the loadStarted event isn't triggered causing the spinner to malfunction. Looks like only links with tel:, mailto: and loc: trigger the loadStarted event. Hope someone can Help out.

XML:

```
<ActionBar #webviewActionbar title="Facilitor" flat="true">
    <ActionItem (tap)="onQrScanTap()" ios.position="right" ios.systemIcon="15" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_camera">
    </ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
<GridLayout rows="*">
    <WebView row="0" #loginView (loaded)="webviewLoaded($event);" (loadStarted)="webviewTrigger($event)" (loadFinished)="onLoadFinished($event)" (doubleTap)="onDoubleTap($event)" (swipe)="onSwipe($event)" [src]="webViewSrc" ></WebView>
    <TextField row="0" [(ngModel)]="registerModel.push_action" #pushActionModel="ngModel" autocorrect="false"
    autocapitalizationType="none" [visibility]="'collapse'" (textChange)="navigateToAction()"></TextField>
    <ActivityIndicator (loaded)="onSpinnerLoaded($event)" rowSpan="2" [busy]="isBusy" (busyChange)="onBusyChanged($event)" width="100" height="100"></ActivityIndicator>
</GridLayout>
```

TypeScript:

```
  private onLoadFinished(args: any) {
    console.log("== onLoadFinished ==");
    this.isBusy = false;
  }
  private webviewTrigger(args: any) {
    console.log("== webviewTrigger ==");
    var webView: WebView = <WebView>args.object;
    console.log(webView);
    // get location
    if (args.url.startsWith('loc:')) {
      let arr = args.url.split(":");
      this.registerModel.push_action = this.registrationService.composeUrl() + arr[1] + "?longitude=" + this.lastLocation.longitude + "&latitude=" + this.lastLocation.latitude;
      this.navigateToAction();
      webView.reload();
      return;
    // handle mailto: and tel:
    } else if (args.url.startsWith('mailto:') || args.url.startsWith('tel:')) {
      utils.openUrl(args.url);
      webView.reload();
      return;
    }
    // start spinner
    this.isBusy = true;
  }
```

Terminal log after tapping some links:

```
JS: == onNavigatingTo ==
chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(51)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
JS: == webviewLoaded ==
JS: WebView(44)
JS: == setHTTPHeader ==
JS: == onSpinnerLoaded ==
JS: == onNavigatedTo ==
JS: == webviewTrigger ==
JS: WebView(44)
JS: indicator.busy changed to: true
JS: ===Location===
JS: == onLoadFinished ==
JS: indicator.busy changed to: false
JS: == onLoadFinished ==
JS: == onLoadFinished ==
JS: == onLoadFinished ==
```

Comment: Can you share a minimal Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced. Also the device details you are testing with, Device Model / OS version etc.,

Comment: I will make a minimal Playground example as soon as I find the time (which may be weeks from now). In the meanwhile unfortunately I will have to disable the spinner for Android.

Comment: You don't have to create a Playground with everything from your project. Probably just load your web page, add load started event and share if the event doesn't hit.

Comment: In node module [webview-utils.android.js] function [onPageStarted] on line 47 there is this If statement: `if (!isHttpRequest || ++this.startEventCount === 1)` The ++ increments **this.startEventCount** while testing **=== 1** which will only be true the first time a pageLoad starts. In my opinion this causes the loadStarted event to be called only once (unless the url starts with [tel:, mailto: or loc:]) Having fixed this locally, I found out that the loadStarted event is triggered too late. Showing the spinner only a few milliseconds before the webpage finished loading.

Comment: Did you try removing the plugin and see if that solves the issues with this event? If it does, you may notify the author and find a workaround after analysing the plugin code.

Comment: When I removed the plugin the [loadStarted] event was triggered, but still too late. Non-trigger and too late trigger both don't work for my App. I will add an issue to the plugin's GitHub page. (nativescript-webview-utils)